# Efficient way to find no of occurances of some property value in object as value of hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have a `HashMap` which has `Object` as value. I want to find no. of all those occurrences of `Object` in `HashMap` value which has some defined value in property. E.g. mentioned below :

```
class Employee{
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
     return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
     this.name = name;
    }
}
Map<Integer, Employee> emp = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();

emp.add(1, E1);
emp.add(2, E2);
```

I want to find the number of occurrences in hashmap where name = "robert".
what is the most efficient way to do it. Can I do it without loops as my hasрmap is very large.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the *without loops* part, not so much the *most efficient way* part: you could do it without loops using Java 8 Streams but that doesn't make it any more efficient per se.

It's theoretically possible that parallelization could help if the Map is really large. Though in this case it is not very likely since the `filter` Predicate is computationally really cheap.

Anyway, parallelization would be easy to achieve with Java 8 Streams.
Assuming your Employee class has a `getName()` method, you could try something like this

```
Map<Integer, Employee> emp = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();

String name = "robert";

long count = emp.values()
        .parallelStream()
        .filter(e -> name.equals(e.getName()))
        .count();
```

**Edit**:

Seems I was a bit too pessimistic with respect to potential runtime improvements due to parallel streams. I did a small test on a quad-core I7 measuring with a HashMap that contains 750_000 entries.

The improvement against the `for` loop approach was consistently about 50%. That is if (and only if!) you dou this over and over again, on average, you could double your processing speed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible, unless you create a sort of order. For example if you put your names where keys are on ascending order, and values are in      lexicographical order, you can put and get name in order with a complexity of O(log2(n)) with a bynary search algorithm.

Other solution is to save dinamically in other structure this kind of information to get more quickly, like an hash map where keys are names, and values are occurrences

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

one simple approach you may try (but not the best)

```
String name = "robert";
int count = 0;
for(Employee theEmployee: emp.values()) {
  if (theEmployee.getName().equals(name)) {
      count++;
  }
}
```

EDIT: I noticed something in your code -> you add to the hashmap like this

```
emp.put(1, E1);
emp.put(2, E2);
emp.put(3, E3);
```

NOT

```
emp.add(1, E1);
emp.add(2, E2);
emp.add(3, E3);
```

Comment: that add was just for reference. Not used in actual code. But in above proposed answer, still the for loop is going. How can I avoid looping as my Hashmap is very large ?